# Using subprocess under django to call a scala program

Tags: python, django, scala, subprocess

I have a scala program that I would like to call from within django using subprocess:

```
encode_cmd = "/usr/local/share/scala/scala-2.10.0/bin/scala -cp /home/django/code/classes conn {}".format(self.id)
output = subprocess.Popen(encode_cmd, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

This code runs fine in the python shell, but when run as part of the normal webserver process it fails to find the scala dependencies (the scala class references the slick libraries for example) failing with the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I've tried specifying specific users as part of the mod_wsgi daemon process, but this makes no difference.

Comment: I don't see you adding any .jars to the classpath. You should jars in your command like that: `-cp /home/django/code/classes:/path/to/slick.jar`, otherwise it only incluses the .class and folders containing class files as per packages.

Comment: BTW, try to the same string from bash and see what it says.

Comment: That appears to do the trick - thank you! - but is there a short hand for adding a number of jar files or do I have to do them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add jars in your command like that: `-cp /home/django/code/classes:/path/to/slick.jar`, otherwise it only includes the .class' and folders containing class files as per packages.

You can always rely on the shell expansion if you have many jars: `/path/to/dependencies/*.jar`

Another option is using SBT's [xsbt-start-script-plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin) or Maven's [appassembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) plugin to create a shell script

Comment: I never got *.jar to work, and still find I have to add the jars individually. That's no great chore, however.